# How to manipulate view based on value from useSelector hook in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am using a requirement to show menus based on roles I get from my auth redux store. I am using `useSelector()` hook to get the roles from redux.

When I try to add if conditions and return different views based on the roles it contains. Below is my code sample.

```
import HeaderButton from '../components/HeaderButton';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  Button,
  Platform,
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
  AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';

import * as siteActions from '../store/actions/sites';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import MenuItem from '../components/MenuItem';

const LandingScreen = props => {
  const roles = useSelector(state => state.auth.roles);
  console.log(roles); //Here I am getting roles as (Admin,User,Approver)
  const selectMenuNavigation = page => {
    if (page === 'Upload') {
      props.navigation.navigate('SelectSite', {
        nextNav: page,
      });
    }
    if (page === 'View') {
      props.navigation.navigate('SelectSite', {
        nextNav: page,
      });
    }
  };

  if (roles.indexOf('Admin') != -1) {
    //roles becomes undefined once I write this line
    return (
      <View>
        <MenuItem
          title="Upload Images"
          onSelect={() => {
            selectMenuNavigation('Upload');
          }}
        />
        <MenuItem
          title="View Images"
          onSelect={() => {
            selectMenuNavigation('View');
          }}
        />
        <MenuItem
          title="Update Sites"
          onSelect={() => {
            selectMenuNavigation('Sites');
          }}
        />
        <MenuItem
          title="Update Users"
          onSelect={() => {
            selectMenuNavigation('Users');
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (roles.indexOf('User') != -1) {
    return (
      <View>
        <MenuItem
          title="Upload Images"
          onSelect={() => {
            selectMenuNavigation('Upload');
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (roles.indexOf('Approver') != -1) {
    return (
      <View>
        <MenuItem
          title="Upload Images"
          onSelect={() => {
            selectMenuNavigation('Upload');
          }}
        />
        <MenuItem
          title="View Images"
          onSelect={() => {
            selectMenuNavigation('View');
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
};

export default LandingScreen;
```

Once write the if conditions the value of `roles` variable becomes `undefined`. Can you help me out here if there is something wrong from the hook implementation point of view.

Comment: is roles an array with these values ["Admin","User","Approver"] ?

Comment: can you add a `console.log` inside one of the `if` statements and make sure your assert is correct - JS guarantees a const reference cannot change, so it's likely you are confusing things

Comment: I fixed the issue after reviewing my code for dispatch. I made sure the dispatch of authenticate action is complete before the navigation occurs to this page. I hope this helps if someone else is facing the issue.